Translation closest to original Heraclitus quote "no man steps in the same river twice, for it is not the same river and he is not the same man"
I know its pretty much impossible to find the original writing, but anything that's close to the original is fine. Or even the orignal translation of someone else paraphrasing him would be cool too.

This https://orb.binghamton.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1252&context=sagp seems promising

As you note, we don't have the original work (only one, according to ancient testimony!) of Heraclitus: instead, we have 100+ extant fragments and/or testimonies of what he said. An old but good source for many of these testimonies is Diels' Die Fragmente der Vorsokratiker (The Fragments of the Pre-Socratics).
In light of this, I want to challenge the wording of your question somewhat. The English sentence you cite is not the "original Heraclitus quote," nor indeed is it even (as far as I can tell) a direct translation of a testimony about what he wrote. A good indication of a poor quote is when the top page of Google results only has vapid posts from Linkedin and social media.
More specifically:

The first part ("No man steps in the same river twice") is a good translation of many extant testimonies.
The second part ("for it is not the same river and he is not the same man") is an explanation that I can't find in any extant testimony.

Greek Testimonies
There are numerous testimonies of the first part. Here are a few:
Plato, Cratylus 402a:

Λέγει που Ἡράκλειτος ὅτι “πάντα χωρεῖ καὶ οὐδὲν
μένει,” καὶ ποταμοῦ ῥοῇ ἀπεικάζων τὰ ὄντα λέγει ὡς “δὶς
ἐς τὸν αὐτὸν ποταμὸν οὐκ ἂν ἐμβαίης.”

My translation:

Heraclitus says somewhere that "all things move and nothing stays," and likening beings to the flow of a river says that "you could not step in the same river twice."

Aristotle, Metaphysics Γ:

Ἡρακλείτῳ ἐπετίμα εἰπόντι ὅτι δὶς τῷ αὐτῷ ποταμῷ οὐκ ἔστιν ἐμβῆναι· αὐτὸς
γὰρ ᾤετο οὐδ’ ἅπαξ.

My translation:

[Cratylus] criticized Heraclitus for saying that it is not possible to step in the same river twice, for he [i.e. Cratylus] himself thought that it wasn't even possible [to step in the same river] once.

Plutarch, De E Apud Delphos, 18:

'ποταμῷ γὰρ οὐκ ἔστιν ἐμβῆναι δὶς τῷ αὐτῷ' καθ’ Ἡράκλειτον οὐδὲ θνητῆς οὐσίας δὶς ἅψασθαι κατὰ ἕξιν· ἀλλ’ ὀξύτητι καὶ τάχει μεταβολῆς ‘σκίδνησι καὶ πάλιν συνάγει’, μᾶλλον δ’ οὐδὲ πάλιν οὐδ’ ὕστερον ἀλλ’ ἅμα συνίσταται καὶ ἀπολείπει καὶ 'πρόσεισι καὶ ἄπεισιν'.

Babbitt's translation:

“‘It is impossible to step twice in the same river’ are the words of Heracleitus, nor is it possible to lay hold twice of any mortal substance in a permanent state ; by the suddenness and swiftness of the change in it there ‘comes dispersion and, at another time, a gathering together’; or, rather, not at another time nor later, but at the same instant it both settles into its place and forsakes its place ; ‘it is coming and going.’

The above references are remarkably consistent in their word choice. Another testimony, however, from a Homeric commentator who (confusingly) is also named Heraclitus has a slightly different version of the quote:
Heraclitus (Commentator), Allegoriae 24.5:

Ποταμοῖς τοῖς αὐτοῖς ἐμβαίνομέν τε καὶ οὐκ ἐμβαίνομεν, εἶμέν τε καὶ οὐκ εἶμεν. . . .

My translation:

We both step and do not step, we both are and are not, in the same rivers.

This testimony is curious for mentioning a "duality": both pairs of the opposition are true.
Latin Testimony
As an added bonus, here is how Seneca translates the phrase into Latin, in his 58th Moral Epistle. Seneca expands the idea somewhat, so it's possible that the quote you cite comes from this reference. His translation seems to be a mix of the quote from Plato and the quote from the commentator Heraclitus, since he uses "twice" but also embraces the two opposites:

Nemo nostrum idem est
in senectute qui fuit iuvenis; nemo nostrum est idem mane
qui fuit pridie. Corpora nostra rapiuntur fluminum more.
Quidquid vides currit cum tempore; nihil ex iis quae videmus
manet; ego ipse, dum loquor mutari ista, mutatus sum. Hoc
est quod ait Heraclitus: 'in idem flumen bis descendimus et
non descendimus'. Manet enim idem fluminis nomen, aqua
transmissa est.

My translation:

None of us is in the same in old age as when he was young. None of us is the same in the morning as he was the day before. Our bodies are taken up like rivers. Whatever you see flows with time. None of the things we see remains. I myself, as I say that these things change, have changed. This is what Heraclitus says: "We go down and do not go down into the same river twice." For the same name of the river remains, but the water has passed through.

